# How to display the value in javascript object array

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

How can I get the value of "Home" & "Away" from the "money_line" in this flow. I want to display the value of Money Line > Home & Away to my table column.

Here's the example data from the ODDS API from RapidAPI.

```
{
    "sport_id": 7,
    "sport_name": "American Football",
    "last": 1694818291,
    "last_call": 1694818291,
    "events": [
        "periods": {
            "num_0": {
                "money_line": {
                    "home": 1.448,
                    "draw": null,
                    "away": 2.92
                },
            },
        }
    ],
}
```

This is how I use to get the Team Names & display it to my table. I just get & follow this code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-json-response-in-ajax/

file: odds.js

```
const fetchBtn = document.getElementById("fetchBtn");
const home_team = document.getElementsByClassName("home_team");
const away_team = document.getElementsByClassName("away_team");

const home_moneyline = document.getElementsByClassName("home_moneyline");
const away_moneyline = document.getElementsByClassName("away_moneyline");

fetchBtn.addEventListener("click", oddsHandler);

function oddsHandler() {
 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "odds.json", true);
    xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.onload = function() {
        const obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Array.from(home_team).forEach((home, index) => {
            home.innerText = obj.events[index].home;
        });

        Array.from(away_team).forEach((away, index) => {
            away.innerText = obj.events[index].away;
        });
        
        // Code from Chuck Terry
        Array.from(money_line).forEach((line, index) => {
          const num = `num_${index}`;
          const team = ['home', 'away'][index];
          line.innerText = obj.periods[num].money_line[team];
        });

    }
    
    xhr.open("GET", URL Host);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", API Key Here);
    
    xhr.send();
    
}
```

index.html

```
<div>        
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Teams</th>
                <th>Money Line</th>
                <th>Handicap</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Total Game</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr>
            <td class="home_team"></td>
            <td class="home_moneyline"></td>
            <td class="home_handicap"></td>
            <td class="home_total"></td>
            <td class="home_totalgame"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="away_team"></td>
            <td class="away_moneyline"></td>
            <td class="away_handicap"></td>
            <td class="away_total"></td>
            <td class="away_totalgame"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button id="fetchBtn" type="button" name="button">Fetch</button>
<script src="odds.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

HTML Outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - Updated to Reflect new Information in Question

This should do the trick:

```js
const fetchBtn = document.getElementById('fetchBtn');
const apiKey = '====  YOUR API KEY HERE  ====';

// Here we are grabbing the row instead of the cell, that way you can
// easily work with other cells if needed
const home_row = Array.from(document.querySelector('.home_team').parent.children);
const away_row = Array.from(document.querySelector('.away_team').parent.children);

// Get the specific Table cell in each row for your money line
const home_moneyline = home_row[1];
const away_moneyline = away_row[1];

fetchBtn.addEventListener('click', oddsHandler);

function oddsHandler() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'odds.json', true);
  xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  
  xhr.onload = function() {
    const object = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    
    // This is how you access the money_line property
    const moneyLine = object.events[0].periods.num_0.money_line;
    
    // And this is where we set the innerText content
    home_moneyline.innerText = moneyLine.home;
    away_moneyline.innerText = moneyLine.away;
  }
  
  xhr.open('GET', URL Host);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-RapidAPI-Key', apiKey);
  xhr.send();
}
```

<s>There's not really enough information for us to figure out what you're trying to accomplish.</s>

It appears that you have an array-like object `home_team` which contains `HTMLElement`s.  You are receiving a JSON string from an XHR and parsing it.  Then Iterating over each item in `home_team` to set its innerText to a value in the parsed JSON string...

Based on that, I would assume you're needing something along the lines of:

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
Array.from(money_line).forEach((line, index) => {
  const num = `num_${index}`;
  const team = ['home', 'away'][index];
  line.innerText = obj.periods[num].money_line[team];
});
```

I kept the code similar to what you're already using.  If you can provide more information about your other variables, table structure, and request structure, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... appreciate it. I did update my question including the code I use. however, the console does have `Uncaught ReferenceError: money_line is not defined`

Comment: Alright, I've updated the answer to account for the additional information.  It should do what you need.  I also commented the code to mark the specific part that accesses the home and away properties on your JSON object :)

Comment: Thanks and I test it.. however this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))` point to this `from(document.querySelector('.home_team').parent);`. btw `.home_moneyline` is the class where i need to display it.

Comment: another error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'num_0')` from this line: `const moneyLine = object.events.periods.num_0.money_line;`

Comment: Edited - I forgot to add children to the row parent accessors, and I missed the fact that events is an array instead of object.  As for .home_moneyline, it's accessed in the variable by the same name.  It seemed like it would be easier for you in case you modify the other fields from the same .js file :)